# webpack bundle empty modules

Tags: typescript, webpack

I am working on a project with webpack + typescript setup. But I'v noticed that after some imports webpack generates a list of empty modules.

e.g. I have a app.ts file which is an entry point, and it has following code:

```
import Information from './utilities/Information';
let info = new Information();
```

./utitlities/Information is class that wraps around platform.js library

```
import platform from 'platform';
export default class Information {
    public getName(): string {
        return platform.name.toLowerCase().replace(' ', '-');
    }
}
```

this causes webpack to produce following code in the bundle:

```
, /* 8 */
, /* 9 */
, /* 10 */
, /* 11 */
, /* 12 */
, /* 13 */
/***/
```

Same thing happens with some locally created imports and exports.

What's happening here and how can I avoid this?

Comment: Do you have any modules that contain only interfaces? If so, type erasure means there will be nothing inside after compilation.

Comment: Yes, I do, how do I avoid that?

Comment: I tend to avoid interface-only files, but if they make sense to you then it is probably worth living with the webpack side of things.